# "premature end of core file" when running SBCL common lisp interpreter

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I tried installing SBCL on Debian 6.0, and I tried to run it to get a lisp interpreter. When I run it, I get the following output:

```
#> sbcl
This is SBCL 1.0.40.0.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 20335(tid 3085240000):
premature end of core file


Welcome to LDB, a low-level debugger for the Lisp runtime environment.
ldb>
```

The fatal error is what bugs me, and I wasn't able to load any files like quicklisp, so it appears my installation is broken. I tried removing it and reinstalling it with apt-get, but got the same result.

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried installing from source or downloading binaries provided at sbcl.org?

Comment: Downloading the binary from http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html worked, but that doesn't explain why the package on debian is broken. Thanks for the suggestion, anyways.

Comment: Yeah sorry, no idea about that. Btw if you compile from source you can make slime cross-reference code of the implementation itself ("How is cl:list defined? Let me take a loook!") Which is why I always compile sbcl from source